# Is it okay to ask a question requesting information on which existing packages provide "a general way to make new brackets"?

Tags: discussion, questions

There is a question which shows how one can draw a new bracket style using `pict2e`, and then apply it for use  as a bracket: [Nice curved brackets (in the shape of \prec and \succ)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220762/nice-curved-brackets-in-the-shape-of-prec-and-succ)

There is a question whose answer goes into a wonderful description of virtual fonts in order to design new brackets: [Design of new brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253614/design-of-new-brackets)

This question's answer describes how to create extensible (stretchy) symbols, which are useful for new bracket shapes that have to be scaled relative to the size of the stuff they are bracketing: [How can I create a new extensible symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109699/how-can-i-create-a-new-extensible-symbol?lq=1)

This question reminds us of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`: [How to declare an operator with automatic argument bracketing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28042/how-to-declare-an-operator-with-automatic-argument-bracketing?rq=1); which is great, except for the delimiters are not extensible.

I'd like to know if there is a general package that handles bracketing by putting together these various aspects. For instance, I give it a shape (either one drawn using `pict2e`, or using a pair of existing glyphs), and then it does some of the finer work in the background (e.g. making the glyphs stretchy, and so on). This would be ideal for someone who is <s>lazy</s> just wanting to get on with writing some math, and not be intimidated by the awesome complexity that is usually carefully hidden from us.

I feel like this might be a question that has already been answered, but I am unable to find it using keywords like "bracket design", "bracket shape", "new bracket shape".

Do you remember a question like this, or a question that produced a package solution like this? If not, would this question be okay for the main site?